# In Python: How to calculate monthly annual average from csv with daily data and plot it by abbreviated month

Tags: python, csv

I just downloaded a huge database of daily data for a climate station in Canada Env, and I thought it will be "easier" for me to write a code to help me have the monthly annual average for a period of 30 years, and continue doing the same for 15 more stations. I am just also starting learning Python in Spyder. So, I would like that someone help with ideas about what functions or how could be the code be. The headings of my csv are: YYYY, MM, DD, Total Rain, Total Precip, Total Snow, Max Temp, Min Temp and Mean Temp. Here is an csv of example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EAbqos89dQXxOpy_hg6v-P2qFKPS37h5/view?usp=sharing

What I would like to have is the average of the precipitation and mean temperature for each month of the year (1 to 12). For precipitation, I first need to calculate the summation of daily precipitation for each month, and then compute the average for the same month for all the years of data. For temperature I need to average the monthly averages of the values (so an average of all the data for all the months gives the exact same result). Once this is done I need to plot both sets of data (precipitation and temperature) using abbreviated months, and also obtain another csv with mean monthly temperature and precipitation for each year (from 1980 to 2010 for example)

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.